# Materialize getInstance(elem) inside AngularJS component's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, instance, materialize

I'm trying to use the `.open()` method of materialize to open a modal component within AngularJS on the page load.

So my component file (loginModal.js) has the following code:

```
angular.module('my-app').component('loginModal', {
    templateUrl:'app/components/templates/loginModal.html',
    controller: loginModalController
})


function loginModalController()
{
    angular.element(document).ready( function(){

        var loginModal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
        var loginModal_options = {};
        var loginModal_instance = M.Modal.init( loginModal, loginModal_options);

        console.log(loginModal_instance);
        loginModal_instance.open();

        var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(loginModal);
        instance.open();


    });
}
```

While the initialization is happening as expected when I'm trying to trigger the open method, through the `loginModal_instance` variable I'm getting

> loginModal_instance.open is not a function

while through `instance` variable I'm getting

> Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Instead, If I'm going to use JQuery, its working

```
function loginModalController()
{    
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.modal').modal();
          $('#login-modal').modal('open');
    });
}
```

Any ideas? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually by using `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()` did the trick.

Comment: In my case, as I remember, the `querySelectorAll()` returned an array of multiple objects with that class while the `querySelector` returned only the first one which was the one I needed to open.

Comment: Thanks, the correct question "
Can you explain me, why happens this ?"